# Is my question about which degree best fits my non-academic career goal appropriate for this site?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-ness, asking-questions

I have a question about the software development job market.

I am interested in knowing whether (in particular) a big company would value a software developer *with a degree in a development-related field* more than a software developer *with an unrelated degree* (such as economics), if we were to consider that both developers are equally capable of doing their job.

I am uncertain as to whether I should ask this question on [academia.stackexchange.com](http://academia.stackexchange.com) or elsewhere.

Comment: It looks off-topic here, because it's not related to the academic world but to the job market.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, where would you suggest I post my question? Is there any appropriate site on the stackexchange network?

Comment: Workplace.SE could be a better fit, but I'm not a user of that site.

Comment: Thank you I'll try that!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this question would not be on topic here, because it is asking about preparation for a non-academic, non-research career.

As stated in the [help center](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> However, please do not ask questions about
>
> ...
>
> Preparation for a non-academic career ("What graduate degree will help me get a job as X?")

Thanks for checking with us first :)